# Using low pass filter for a differential ended receiver system?

Tags: passive-networks

I want to use anti-aliasing filters in different scenarios. Below is the topology for how to use a passive LP filter in the case of a single ended transducer and single ended data acquisition:

[image]

How should the RC the connection be:

1-) If the source is diff ended and the data acq. is also diff ended?

2-) If the source is single ended and the data acq. is diff ended?

Could you illustrate these two cases by drawing like mine above.

Edit regarding an answer:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the source is diff ended and the data acq. is also diff ended?

If the DAQ input is differential then you need to attenuate the differential signal at higher frequencies so, use resistors in series with each input and a capacitor directly across the DAQ input after the resistors.

> If the source is single ended and the data acq. is diff ended?

You do exactly the same because you don't want to imbalance the impedance of lines that could pick up external inteference (common-mode) and, due to those impedance imbalances, convert a common mode interference to a differential interference.

[image]

You might also need to consider impedance balancing at the source and cabling between source and DAQ. You might also need common mode decoupling capacitors to help reduce noise. This is for noise reduction rather than anti-alias filtering.

Comment: Thanks I need to be more clear about it. So I drew your  circuit in a way with all wrings explicit. It is in my edit or here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj7sa.png Now In Fig 1 for DE to DE I guess it is correct? How about Fig 2? I have to use Rbias for commonmode voltage problems for floating SE to DE wirings. Is Fig 2 also correct?

Comment: I would use AIGND feeding two resistors; one to DAQ+ and one to DAQ-. Value depends on DAQ but 10 kohm to 1 Mohm should work. It will work for either set up. Beware of ground loops as per your fig1.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4gDU.png ??

Comment: Yes I do. It works for both. I might be tempted to put 1 nF capacitors in parallel with those 10k resistors to help reduce the impact of common mode noises picked up on the line. Depending on your signal bandwidth and potential interference the capacitors could be uF in value.

Comment: And does the cut of of the LP same formula ? 1/(2*pi*R*C)? Need know it for anti-aliasing filter.

Comment: Yes, it can have an effect. You can model this in a sim for better understanding but, in effect, each 10k has the effect of being in parallel with the series resistance in each input lead. There is also a signal voltage attenuation due to them forming potential dividers. I would suggest you use a free sim to model this rather than have extended discussions in comments.

Comment: Yes I will do that and can I open a new question regarding that? Something more specific. Thanks

Comment: [Try this for a start](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140195/trying-to-determine-the-output-of-a-rc-filter-with-load)

Comment: I opened a new question ultimately related to this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358721/a-signal-wiring-question-about-a-single-ended-to-differential-ended-system

Comment: Can I use inductors instead of 100 Ohms(LC low pass filter)? I was thinking I would even reduce the voltage divider effect coming from 100 Ohms. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes you can but be aware that you need to produce a low-pass circuit with a Q not greater than 0.7071 to avoid [peaking](http://www.analog.com/-/media/images/analog-dialogue/en/volume-41/number-4/articles/phase-relations-in-active-filters/ad41-10_18.jpg?la=en) close to resonance

Answer (score 2):

This circuit is even more robust against both differential and against common mode trash

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvUo9y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please notice C1 and C2 share a COMMON GROUND. :This is on purpose.

===================== April 2020

If the capacitors or resistors are IMBALANCED, are not of precisely the same value, the rejection of CommonMode energy will be VERY POOR. This means the mis-etching of PCB traces will have some effect. You can simulate this impairment.

Whether you can succeed with inductors will depend on the frequencies of interest and the frequencies to reject; also the matching of the inductors will matter, as matching matters for Rs and Cs. Inductors will be more susceptible to external magnetic fields.

Comment: Woow this works much better, I checked in simulation. With this one I can even use R3 and R4 bias resistors bigger like 100k and load the source less and get rid of common mode. C3 is setting the LP filter cut off together with 100 Ohm resistors I guess.

Comment: Do you think adding a 10nF between the source terminals have a good effect for high frequency noise as well?

Comment: Can I use inductors instead of 100 Ohms(LC lowpass filter)? I was thinking I would even reduce the voltage divider effect coming from 100 Ohms. Does it make sense?